# Desmarcar Radio Button do Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Ola, eu estou com um problema no Angular. Eu quero que meu button select do Angular Material seja desmarcado(uncheck) quando a seguinte função for chamada, porem não faço a minima ideia de como fazer, alguem poderia me ajudar?.
Vou colocar os codigos aqui em baixo.

Codigo da função

```
uncheckRadio(){
  alert('Botao desmarcado')
}
```

Codigo do meu Radio Button:

```
<div  class="form-group col-md6 form-md-checkboxes">
   <label>Instância</label>
   <mat-radio-group (change)="radioChange($event)" formControlName="status">
   <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="primeira">Primeira Instancia</mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="segunda">Segunda Instancia</mat-radio-button>
   </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso basta setar nulo no teu control.

No exemplo abaixo eu criei um botão para chamar o método **uncheckRadio**

```
<div  class="form-group col-md6 form-md-checkboxes">
    <label>Instância</label>
    <mat-radio-group (change)="radioChange($event)" formControlName="status">
      <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="primeira">Primeira Instancia</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button color="primary" value="segunda">Segunda Instancia</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <button mat-raised-button class="restore-button" (click)="uncheckRadio()">Restore Defaults</button>
  </div>
```

No arquivo ts eu pego o control no formGroup e reseto o valor ou seto null.

```
uncheckRadio() {
   this.formGroup.get('status').reset();
   // Ou pode ser feito assim: this.formGroup.get('status').setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: Estou com o seguinte erro: [ts] Property 'formGroup' does not exist on type 'QuerySearchDcComponent'.

Comment: O **this.formGroup** é nada mais que uma variável do tipo **FormGroup** que criei no arquivo **.ts**. Eu fiz assim porque vi no teu código de exemplo o **formControlName="status"** então imaginei que está usando *ReactiveForms* no teu desenvolvimento. Basta substituir o **this.formGroup** pela variável do teu **FormGroup**. De qualquer forma deixo aqui [neste link o exemplo completo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hkucv) do meu código.